# Serial parsing strange data

Tags: serial, array

I have a project where I use a software serial connection to read serial data from a barcode scanner.

All is good. However from time to time I have some problems with the data that I'm receiving.

> You said : 123456789��?�: @���?���?���?���?���?
>
> You said : 123456789
>
> You said : 123456789123456
>
> You said : 987654321789456123

My code is something similar to the one below

```cpp
int count = 0; 
void parseSerial() {
  char ser[20];
  while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    char c = Serial.read();
    if ( c != '\r' && count <= sizeof(ser)) {
      ser[count] = c;
      count++;
    } else {
      Serial.print("You said : ");
      Serial.println(ser);
      for(int i=0; i < sizeof(ser); i++) {
        ser[i] = '\0';
      }
      count = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea on how I can get rid of "��?�: @���?���?���?���?���?"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the buffer is not initialized to start with. When
you call `parseSerial()`, it contains garbage, which is what you see on
the serial monitor. In order to avoid printing out that garbage, you
have to properly terminate the string, i.e. add a `\0` after the last
valid character.

You did that *after* printing the string (you filled the whole buffer
with `\0`, which is overkill), but that's too late. The subsequent
printouts are OK though.

The recommended way to handle incoming serial data is to look for a
terminating character (`\r` seems to be what you expect), and buffer
all the incoming bytes until you see it. Don't forget to save 1 byte of
buffer space for the terminating `\0`:

```c++
void parseSerial() {
    static char buffer[20];
    static int count = 0;

    while (Serial.available()) {
        int c = Serial.read();
        if (c == '\r') {           // received complete line
            buffer[count] = '\0';  // terminate the string
            Serial.print(F("You said: "));
            Serial.println(buffer);
            count = 0;
        }
        else if (count < sizeof buffer - 1) {
            buffer[count++] = c;
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that the buffer here being static, you can accumulate partial
messages through successive calls to `parseSerial()`. Only when the
message is complete will it print it back.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using char array when you can use String. And use Serial.readStringUntil('\r'); instead Serial.read.

Code:

```cpp
void parseSerial(){
String read = " ";
int count = 0;
if(Serial.available()>0){ 
while(Serial.available()>0){ 

if(count != 20){ 
read = Serial.readStringUntil('\r');
count++;
}
}

}
Serial.println("You said: ");
Serial.print(read);
}
```